# How to const reference an object in the c++ for range loop

Tags: c++, stdmap

In the following code, `[id, name]` is a const reference. However, studentMap is non-const. The user can change the value of studentMap in the loop.
I want to ask whether there is a way to make the StudentMap also const. Thanks.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>


int main() {
    std::map<int, std::string> studentMap;
    studentMap[1] = "Tom";
    studentMap[7] = "Jack";
    studentMap[15] = "John";

    for (const auto& [id, name] : studentMap) {
        studentMap.at(id) += "test";
    }

    for (const auto& [id, name]: studentMap) {
        std::cout << id << " " << name << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need `studentMap` to be non-const as you are setting that up before the loops.  So, you could do something like creating a new scope (e.g. a new function), have a const ref referring to `studentMap`, and iterate thru that `constStudentMap`

Comment: You can also create a new variable instead of a new function: `const auto& constStudentMap = studentMap;`

Answer (score 3):

No I don't think it is possible to change the type of a variable.

If you want to avoid unexpected mistake of modifying `studentMap`, you could pull the logic into a separate function, and refer `studentMap` with a const ref:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

void displayStudentMap(const auto& studentMap) {
    for (const auto& [id, name] : studentMap) {
        // compilation error
        studentMap.at(id) += "test";
    }

    for (const auto& [id, name]: studentMap) {
        std::cout << id << " " << name << "\n";
    }

}

int main() {
    std::map<int, std::string> studentMap;
    studentMap[1] = "Tom";
    studentMap[7] = "Jack";
    studentMap[15] = "John";

    displayStudentMap(studentMap);
}
```

Comment: thanks,  can it implement using some semantics like const casting.

Comment: @amont Can you clarify, please, which semantics for example? `const_cast` generally is a red flag for bad design in most cases.

Comment: Beware: using `auto` as parameter creates a templated function. To save repeated typing an alias with `using` could be created instead.

Comment: On my complier, I can't transfer function parameter as auto.

Comment: Which C++ standard did you set for compilation?

Comment: @Sebastian I tried both c++17 and c++2a

Comment: You can see the compiler support for this feature in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/20 (P1141R2: Yet another approach for constrained declarations)

Comment: C++ does not allow `auto` in parameter declarations -- that is provided by a non-standard compiler extension. To be compliant you want `std::map<int, std::string>& studentMap` You can't pass as `const` if you modify with `+= "test";` Both are easily fixed by either removing `const` or not modifying `studentMap` in the function.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin the feature is parts of concepts. E.g. you can say `Sortable auto` to constrain the type to follow a concept. It was officially added to C++20 in the San Diego meeting in 2018. Before it could be used as a pre-standard feature with gcc since version 4.9. I think the OP was modifying with "test" as an example, where the compiler *should* complain for a constant variable or parameter.

Comment: @Sebastian -- thank you. I've learned something new. I'm still digesting C++17 changes. The changes in C++20 and 23 seem to be coming at an accelerated pace. Glad to see the language pressing forward with features. I just hope the deduction logic is up to the task.

Answer (score 3):

This way:

```
const std::map<int, std::string> studentMap {
    std::make_pair(1, "Tom"),
    std::make_pair(7, "Jack"),
    std::make_pair(15, "John")
};
```

or this with C++11 uniform initialization:

```
const std::map<int, std::string> studentMap {
        { 1, "Tom" },
        { 7, "Jack" },
        { 15, "John" }
};
```